# merge some ogg audio files using java programming language

Tags: java, audio, html5-audio, mediarecorder

I have some .ogg sound files that must be merged together.But the problem is in that the java only support .wav extension (as I used AudioSystem and AudioInputStream).

I've searched among different pages for converting and I've not found a better way than.

Do you know a better way other than using Command line tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to inspect and tinker with the source code. This can be obtained from various libraries that have *JOrbis* and other files needed for ogg playback and encoding (there are several on github).

For a project where I needed to load decompressed ogg files (that were originally wav) into memory, I used source code from the example `OggPlayer` (usually included in the package) and intercepted the bytes before they were written to a `SourceDataLine`. You can maybe also find a hook in example code that compresses wav to ogg and then link the two parts.